# Differentiate contacts as donors vs. class participants

Tags: contacts

I need to differentiate contacts who are donors to our organization from those who are class participants. Some will be both but funds need to be differentiated. How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! This sounds like a good question but you could make it better if you could edit it to provide more detail about what you are trying to achieve.  Please also include the version of CiviCRM and the CMS you are using (e.g. Drupal, WordPress or Joomla).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, it really depends on what you want to achieve. The simple and basic way would be to use a tag to flag if someone is a class participant or a donor? But I would really need more description of what you want to achieve to give you a good answer!